# Stress testing software (but I need run it step by step) with locust

Tags: stress-testing, locust

as question in the Title 
what I meant step by step is like : 
-signup
-get course
-choose course
all those three must be in order , step by step

FYI
I already make it on on_start but the status result is never correct
for example : 
I set number of users 100
I set end point of "/signup" and then 
I see 55 on table status of that end point , but on reality we have 100 users registered on database

what I suppose to do, to make it properly work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the reply
anw I just solved by my self, the issue is after hacth finish
locust always reset the stat automatically even in the middle of test that run and that mess up the stat .
(sry for my bad english)

and after I comment that code in locust folder
eveything is going well

Answer (score 2):

Since Locust tasks are normally executed randomly, you probably want to do all of those steps in the same task to be sure that they are all executed after each other in order. You can insert calls to the TaskSet's `wait()` method in between (or just call `time.sleep()` manually) to simulate that the user waits between the actions.

Something like this might work:

```
class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.client.post("/signup")
        self.wait()
        self.client.get("/get-course")
        self.wait()
        self.client.post("/select-course")
        self.wait()
```

Regarding the issue of you seeing 55 requests in the statistics even though it seems like a 100 requests are actually made (at least that's how I interpret your text), that sounds like it might be because Locust resets the statistics once all users have been spawned during the ramp-up phase.